# Плохо работает jquery.maskedinput

Tags: html, jquery, inputmask

У меня как-то криво работает маска на ввод телефона.
Скорее всего это опять какие-то неполадки из-за webpack, но всё же.
Импорчу сам файл [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Потом в index.js пишу вот такой вот код: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И в консоли по итогу выдаёт такую ошибку : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Всё как бы работает, но криво. Когда я только нажимаю на input, маска не появляется, но как только напишу любую цифру - появляется.
Как сделать так, что бы маска появлялась сразу, когда инпут попадает в фокус?[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]